# Axios failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello there hope you are doing well!

I'm tring to fetch some data from the db but for some reason the request goes through in postman but when I try it with axios is gives me:

400 bad request Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Here is my code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchItems = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/orderhis',
                    {data: {"user_id":87}}
                );
                setData(response.data)
            } catch(err) {
                if (err.response) {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                    console.log(err.response.status);
                    console.log(err.response.headers);
                }
                else{
                    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
                }
            }
        }
        fetchItems();
    }, []);
```

In Postman:

[image: Postman example]

But in the Browser:

[image]

PS Here is the route code in case it helps:

```
def order_history():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user_id = request.json['user_id']
        is_user = BaseUser().getUserID(request.json)
        if is_user[1] == 404:
            return is_user
        return OrderController().get_order_history(user_id)
    return jsonify(Error='Method not allowed'), 405
```

Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You're setting params like this: `{data: {"user_id":87}}`, but in axios you need to set params with: `{params: {"user_id":87}}`